# How to create a relational data table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have the following Table1 in Excel

```
Name    Age Sex
Pablo   28  Male
Victor  32  Male
Juan    33  Male
Pedro   40  Male
Jacinta 24  Female
Laura   39  Female
```

And Table2

```
Sex    Color
Male   Blue
Female Pink
```

How can I create a table (or pivot table, or just a simple Excel range) that can relate both tables through the Sex field?

```
Name    Age Color
Pablo   28  Blue
Victor  32  Blue
Juan    33  Blue
Pedro   40  Blue
Jacinta 24  Pink
Laura   39  Pink
```

I know I can use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`-`MATCH`, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution using Excel data model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `VLOOKUP` within an `IF` statement to look up the name and get the value of the 3rd column. Then see if it equals `Male`. If its true, return Blue. If its false, return Pink.

`=IF(VLOOKUP(A18,Table1[#All],3,FALSE)="Male", $H$2, $H$3)`

I created the table example you gave at `A1` and made it `Table1`. Then created `Table2` at `G1:H3`. I created the new table at `A17:C23`, thus the reference to `A18` at the begining of the `VLOOKUP`.

[image]